# I was watching a tutorial of tensorflow. The input layer has 10 units , 2 hidden layers with 50 units each and output layer has 2 units

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

But there is no input layer in Sequential.

```
input_layer=10
output_layers=2
hidden_layers=50
model=Sequential([
                 Dense(units=hidden_layers,activation="relu"),
                 Dense(units=hidden_layers,activation="relu"),
                 Dense(units=output_layers,activation="softmax")
                 ])
batch_size=100
max_epochs=100
model.compile(optimizer="Adam",loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(train_inputs,train_targets,batch_size=batch_size,epochs=max_epochs,
          validation_data=(validation_inputs,validation_targets),verbose=2)
```

How does this work? why there is no input layer in sequential arrangement?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify input shape in advance, TensorFlow will figure out it later, when model is run with concrete input data ("mode.fit(...)" call in your case).

It can be still useful to specify input shape using "Input" layer, so that you can use "model.summary()" function before running the model on concrete input. Please see the following for a detailed explanation:
https://keras.io/guides/sequential_model/